# Transformando objetos de objeto em um objeto com um único nível

Tags: javascript

Tudo bom?

Atualmente eu tenho uma função que transforma strings em objetos, dou um split(".") e passo o array como parâmetro, show, tenho meu objeto preenchido.

```js
function changeObject(path, value, obj = {}) {
  const lastKey = path.pop();
  let curr = obj;
  for (let key of path) {
    curr = curr[key] || {};
  }
  curr[lastKey] = value;
  return obj;
}

let proposal = {
  id: 123,
  customer: {
   name: "Fulano",
   lastName: "Da Silva",
   address: {
     street: ""
   }
  }
}
let string = "customer.address.street";
let obj = changeObject(string.split("."), "Rua ABC", proposal)
// retorna meu objeto proposal com street preenchido "Rua ABC"
```

Porém preciso também de uma função que transforma este objeto com vários níveis em um objeto com apenas um nível onde os níveis são separados por pontos Ex:

```js
//O Objeto Antes estaria assim
let proposal = {
  id: 123,
  customer: {
   name: "Fulano",
   lastName: "Da Silva",
   address: {
     street: "Rua ABC"
   }
  }
}

//Após passar pela função o objeto proposal estaria assim ou retornaria um novo objeto assim:

proposal = {"customer.name": "Fulano", "customer.lastName": "Da Silva", "customer.address.street": "Rua ABC"}
```

Acho que eu teria que usar recursividade

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta aqui. Acho que é oq tu queres.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134212/best-way-to-flatten-js-object-keys-and-values-to-a-single-depth-array

Comment: Show de Bola... Obg Calixto. A função flattenObject era o que eu precisava